# How to show multiple vehicles of the same model variant as a single list item in flutter app

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, data-structures

Firestore data structure

[image]

Client Side ScreenShot

[image]

How to show multiple vehicles of same car variant as a single item in list on the flutter client while also querying their availability separately? Please suggest the best practices to handle this.

To show available vehicles, I go through the Bookings subcollection, comparing it with input start & end date for any conflicts and then switch the Vehicle visibility in the list with a boolean.

Comment: Please include codes

Comment: @KaushikChandru I assume it's something to with data structure so not sure if client side code would be helpful. what do you say ?

Comment: If it's a list you can take unique items from it